# Index an array using a callback function to get the key

Tags: php

Is there a built-in PHP function that does the following?

```php
function array_index(array $values, callable $getKey): array
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $result[$getKey($value)] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I think I've reviewed all `array_*()` functions, but am surprised that this use case is not covered by any native function.

Comment: array_walk? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: @Andy How does that help. The question doesn't want to get the keys, it wants to create keys in a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function that does this in one step. But you can use `array_map()` to get the new keys from the function, and `array_combine()` to merge those with the original values to create the associative array.

```
$result = array_combine(array_map($getKey, $values), $values);
```